# NavigationBar changed in iOS10

Tags: ios, ios10

I use the following code to setup left & right bar item,

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-back"]
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(leftItemTapped:)];
```

Now it stopped working in iOS 10, the items are not "clickable"

Any one know how to fix that?

Comment: Try if a standard System-Button would work: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(leftItemTapped)];`

Comment: By the way, how you do it, works like a charm for me on iOS 10. I'm setting it in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in `viewWillAppear`, and it should work properly...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-back"]
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(leftItemTapped:)];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-back"]
                                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(leftItemTapped:)];

}


- (IBAction)leftItemTapped:(id)sender{
     NSLog(@"Navigation");
}


Output:
2016-09-15 15:30:00.972 test[34398:248335] Navigation
```